# Django Blog Adding published_date field to new posts and ability to login as non-admin

Tags: django

The tutorial I'm following: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/README.html

I got through it all the way to step 21.  However, when I click the + button in the corner for a new post it lets me add it and validates the empty fields.  But it doesn't add the post to the list of posts.  Everything else works, i can edit forms fine, they save and display.  But when I add the post with the + button in the top right I can only see it in the /admin part of the site.  It doesn't show up on the main page of the si

EDIT: 
By reading https://github.com/DjangoGirls/tutorial-extensions/blob/master/homework/README.md the tutorial extensions, I discovered that it is intentional that the posts without a published_date are not shown.

My question now is how to add a published_date field that is filled for non-admins, as well as how to allow for a user to login as a non admin author when posting without visiting the admin part of the site at all.

I know my question devolved into more of a "how do i do X?"  But I don't need an exact answer, just some guidance.

Someone familiar with django would probably be able to answer the question easily.

Comment: in your view you could write posts = Posts.objects.all() to get all posts, now you filter with the published date

Comment: Thanks yes I figured that out by reading the tutorial extensions.  But I'm still trying to figure out how to have published_date filled in as the current time/date automatically for a non admin user, as well as add their name as an author (which I assume requires some sort of registration feature)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To automaticly add a date to you post you only have to add an option to you model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

published_date = models.DateTimeField(**auto_now_add=True**
                blank=True, null=True)

Or just **auto_now** if you want to update the date whenever the model is saved / updated

On the other hand there is a publish function, which porvides this functionality. You could also add a button where you call this function and it will fill out the date for you, when you publish the post.

Comment: I think your answer is correct and almost fully answers my question.  Where should i put this class?  Also, as far as user registration and groups go, I know that Django has a built in system in the admin section.  But other than adding people by hand there is no way for people to register.  There is also no way to enable certain permissions for each group from the base interface.  What do you recommend to accomplish these tasks?

Comment: Well you put this class in the models.py file. I took it from the tutorial. AS for the registration: there are some apps for this e.g. registration redux which provides you with a nice solution for user registration.

Comment: class Post(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     text = models.TextField()
     created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
     published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,      null=True) 


This is what i had in models.py before almost the same, i'll test the new one you showed me and accept your answer if all goes well :)

Comment: It worked !!! Thanks a bunch.  Although I had to fix the tabs and a comma was missing befoore blank=True

Comment: what does auto_now_add=True do?  And where can I find documentation for it?

Comment: The docs are at the link. It adds thr time when the object was first created.