# Using a class object in another class in models.py [Django]

Tags: python, django, class

I am writing a blog application in Django. In the models.py I have two classes: Post and LanguageCategory. In language category I would predefine which languages are applicable such as English, Italian, and this could be created by superuser in admin login. However, inside the Post class I want to use the LanguageCategory class as a property called languages as follows (code for models.py):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536180/django-blog-adding-published-date-field-to-new-posts-and-ability-to-login-as-non
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="some keywords here")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
            blank=False, null=False)
    language = LanguageCategory()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images/', default='blog_images/myimage.png')
    body = models.TextField()

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)


class LanguageCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I try to make migrations I get the following error:

> line 15, in Post
> language = LanguageCategory() NameError: name 'LanguageCategory' is not defined

How to fix this issue and how can I use LanguageCategory in the Post such that the blog posts has a field which selects the languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could foreign key. And instead of direct reference, you could quote it like following.

```
language = models.ForeignKey('LanguageCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The full code as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536180/django-blog-adding-published-date-field-to-new-posts-and-ability-to-login-as-non
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="some keywords here")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
            blank=False, null=False)
    language = models.ForeignKey('LanguageCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images/', default='blog_images/myimage.png')
    body = models.TextField()

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)


class LanguageCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='english', primary_key = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#lazy-relationships

Comment: btw when I am doing makemigrations it is saying: ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'english'. what should be the default value in language in Post?

Comment: Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create its database column name. In the above example, the database table for the Car model will have a manufacturer_id column. (You can change this explicitly by specifying db_column) However, your code should never have to deal with the database column name, unless you write custom SQL. You’ll always deal with the field names of your model object.

Comment: should it be something like this--> class LanguageCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='english', primary_key = True)

Comment: Could you post your whole error traceback? for Django Model, it adds id field as default.